# Cannot activate python virtual env in jenkins shell script

Tags: command-line, bash, python, jenkins

I have installed Jenkins on ubuntu 15.10. In a shell build step I am trying to create a Python virtual environment and activate it:
[image]

But I get the following error when I run the job:

```
/tmp/hudson4515625893361069094.sh: 9: /tmp/hudson4515625893361069094.sh: source: not found
```

More from the log:

```
[django-demo] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson4515625893361069094.sh
+ virtualenv --no-site-packages virtual_django
New python executable in virtual_django/bin/python2
Also creating executable in virtual_django/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python2
+ cd virtual_django/bin
+ pwd
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/django-demo/virtual_django/bin
+ dir
activate      activate.fish easy_install      pip   pip2.7  python2
activate.csh  activate_this.py  easy_install-2.7  pip2  python  python2.7
+ source activate
/tmp/hudson4515625893361069094.sh: 9: /tmp/hudson4515625893361069094.sh: source: not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

So the virtual environment was created successfully but it cannot be activated because the **source** command cannot be found.

I did verify that I can indeed run the **source activate**  command from a terminal on the machine as the jenkins user in the corresponding workspace:

```
jenkins@vmi63860 ~/workspace/django-demo/virtual_django/bin ((HEAD detached at 290c6a4)) $ source activate
(virtual_django)jenkins@vmi63860 ~/workspace/django-demo/virtual_django/bin ((HEAD detached at 290c6a4)) $ exit
```

So why does it fail when I run it under the Jenkins job?

Answer (score 6):

Found a similar post here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670191/getting-a-source-not-found-error-when-using-source-in-a-bash-script

The solution is to add:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

in the first line of the script step:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

source is a bash/ksh/etc extension, provided as a more "substantial" synonym for .

Try using below

```
. activate
```

Comment: As you say, "." and "source" are synonymous.  This should make no difference.